# Error al actualizar datos PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]

Tags: php

Necesito ayuda, no soy muy bueno en php, pero al intentar verificar si esto funciona en POSTMAN me dice :

> Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid
>   parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of
>   tokens in
>   /storage/ssd4/970/3632970/public_html/ArchivosPHP/login.php:77
>
> Stack trace: 0
>   /storage/ssd4/970/3632970/public_html/ArchivosPHP/login.php(77):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) 1
>   /storage/ssd4/970/3632970/public_html/ArchivosPHP/Actualizar.php(6):
>   Registro::ActualizarInformacion('correo@g...', 'Nombre', 'Apellidos',
>   '01', '01', '2017', 'Genero', 'Contraseña') 2 {main}   thrown in
>   /storage/ssd4/970/3632970/public_html/ArchivosPHP/login.php on line 77

Este es el método:

```
public static function ActualizarInformacion($correo,$nombre,$apellidos,$dia,$mes,$anio,$sexo, $contra){
            if(self::ObtenerUsuariosPorId($correo)){
                $consultar = "UPDATE DatosPersonales SET correo = ?, nombre = ?, apellidos = ?, dia = ?,mes = ?,anio = ?,sexo = ? ,contra = ? WHERE correo = ?";
                $resultado = Database::getInstance()->getDb()->prepare($consultar);
                return $resultado->execute(array($correo,$nombre,$apellidos,$dia,$mes,$anio,$sexo,$contra));
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
```

La línea 77 es:

```
return $resultado->execute(array($correo,$nombre,$apellidos,$dia,$mes,$anio,$sexo,$contra));
```

Aquí el otro archivo php:

```
<?php
require 'login.php';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $datos = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
    $respuesta = Registro::ActualizarInformacion($datos["correo"],$datos["nombre"],$datos["apellidos"],$datos["dia"],$datos["mes"],$datos["anio"],$datos["sexo"],$datos["contra"]);
    if($respuesta){
        echo "Se Actualizaron los datos correctamente";
    }else{
        echo "EL usuario no existe";
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que crear un array válido para pasarlo al `execute`, en el cual haya tantos parámetros como marcadores tenga la consulta. Dado que **tienes que pasar dos veces el correo**, no puedes usar marcadores de posición `?`, sino que tendrás que cambiarlos por marcadores de nombre, para así poder diferenciar los dos parámetros que necesitas de `correo`:

```
public static function ActualizarInformacion($correo,$nombre,$apellidos,$dia,$mes,$anio,$sexo, $contra){
            if(self::ObtenerUsuariosPorId($correo)){
                $consultar = "UPDATE DatosPersonales SET 
                                correo = :correo, 
                                nombre = :nombre, 
                                apellidos = :apellidos, 
                                dia = :dia, 
                                mes = :mes, 
                                anio = :anio, 
                                sexo = :sexo, 
                                contra = :contra 
                              WHERE correo = :correo_where";
                $resultado = Database::getInstance()->getDb()->prepare($consultar);
                $arrParams=array(
                                    ':correo' => $correo, 
                                    ':nombre' => $nombre, 
                                    ':apellidos' => $apellidos, 
                                    ':dia' => $dia,
                                    ':mes' => $mes,
                                    ':anio' => $anio,
                                    ':sexo' => $sexo,
                                    ':contra' => $contra,
                                    ':correo_where'=>$correo
                                );
                return $resultado->execute($arrParams);
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: El problema termino, muchas gracias, pero ahora el resultado me arroja "el usuario no existe"

Comment: @JuanCarlosRuiz entonces es posible que haya **otro problema** en tu programa, por ejemplo aquí: `if(self::ObtenerUsuariosPorId($correo)){`, no está encontrando usuarios con ese correo. Pero eso sería ya otra cosa. Recomendaría que des por solucionada esta pregunta y cuando tengas ubicado el nuevo error plantées una nueva, si no logras resolverlo. Saludos.